# load key value pairs in consul using consul_kv ansible module

Tags: ansible, consul

we have key value pairs in a file with json format.

```
{
  "app1":
 [
     {"key": "key1","value": "val1"},
     {"key": "key2","value": "val2"}


 ],
  "app2":
 [
      {"key": "key1","value": "val1"},
     {"key": "key2","value": "val2"}

 ],
  "app3":
 [
     {"key": "key1","value": "val1"},
     {"key": "key2","value": "val2"}

 ]
}
```

I want to put these values in consul cluster. here is what i am trying

```
- debug: msg='key contains {{key}}'
  with_consul_kv:
  - 'config/app1/'
  register: keys

 - name: add a kv pair to the kv store
   consul_kv: key=somekey value=somevalue
   register: new_key
```

Comment: What is the exact question?

Comment: i am able to read the key values from json file and not able to upload to consul using consul_kv module

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I have updated the question with mode details..

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov do you have any suggestion on this?

Comment: I still don't understand your question. I see you get all `dc1` keys, and what should be done with next task?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I just updated the playbook with what i  am trying. Here is what i want. I have a json file and i would like to read all the keys and values and update to consul key values at   http://:<<consulhost>>//dc1/kv/config/app1/

Answer (score 0):

when your're not dependant on your JSON structure, you could use a format like:

```
myitems:
 - site:
      - {"key": "abcUrl","value": "http://prod.abc.url"}
      - {"key": "user.url","value": "http://prod.abc.login"}
      - {"key": "security.logout.url","value": "http://prod.abc.logout"}
 - site:
      - {"key": "abcUrl","value": "http://prod.abc.url"}
      - {"key": "user.url","value": "http://prod.abc.login"}
      - {"key": "security.logout.url","value": "http://prod.abc.logout"}
 - site:
      - {"key": "abcUrl","value": "http://prod.abc.url"}
      - {"key": "user.url","value": "http://prod.abc.login"}
      - {"key": "security.logout.url","value": "http://prod.abc.logout"}
 - site:
      - {"key": "abcUrl","value": "http://prod.abc.url"}
      - {"key": "user.url","value": "http://prod.abc.login"}
      - {"key": "security.logout.url","value": "http://prod.abc.logout"}
```

(If you need the dc[1-4] inside for somethin, write it on the key/level.)

With this format you could extract key/value like this:

```
- name: remove a key from the store
  debug:
    msg: "key is {{ item.1.key }} and the value is {{ item.1.value }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ myitems }}"
    - site
```